# Postgres - I don't have a superuser and I can't create a role or I can't grant access to any other user as a superuser

Tags: database, postgresql, azure, psql

I'm currently working through postgres migration, and for some reason the database doesn't allow me to login as the superuser. I also tried to reset the password from the superuser user and I can't.

The services are running through Azure, and the type of server is called Postgres SQL flexible server.

Commands that I have ran already:

```
ALTER ROLE [USER] WITH SUPERUSER;
ALTER ROLE [USER] WITH PASSWORD '[NEW-PASSWORD]'
```

The type of error that I'm getting is the following:

```
Error: Must be superuser to create superuser
```

What could be the best way to solve this situation? Does anyone knows how to force the creation of a superuser?

Comment: So not related to SQL Server at all - tag removed.

Comment: If you have access to the server terminal with root access, try: `sudo su postgres` `psql` then run the commands you mentioned

Comment: AZURE Postgres SQL flexible server is a managed database, Azure manage backup/restore/replication/monitoring. you can't connect as superuser and there is some limitation (cf, no possibility to create tablespace) Azure PGSQL has an admin user, that has almost all privilege. it is max you can have

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. However, the issue that I'm having is with uploading the schemas to the new database. It is telling me that I have an error when I run the query. That error message is the following: must be owner of extension plpsql. Do you know what else I can do to fix this situation? I thought this issues was related to the superuser..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The admin user is the highest privilege user you have on the server. It belongs to the role azure_pg_admin. This role does not have full superuser permissions.
The PostgreSQL superuser attribute is assigned to the azure_superuser, which belongs to the managed service. You do not have access to this role. You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/concepts-servers).

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. However, the issue that I'm having is with uploading the schemas to the new database. It is telling me that I have an error when I run the query. That error message is the following: must be owner of extension plpsql. Do you know what else I can do to fix this situation? I thought this issues was related to the superuser..

Comment: And this is what we call a breaking change. It breaks a lot of things.